# Child under multiple parents LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I Have a child component C in lwc. I have 2 parents **P1** and **P2** which are childs of the main parent
**P**. so below  is the architecture
**P** contains **P1** and **P2**.
**P1** and **P2** contain **C**.
I pass from P1 and P2 a string value to child but the child onle takes value of the first parent even in **P2**.

Main Parent :

```
<template>
        <lightning-card>      
                <c-p1></c-p1>
                <c-p2></c-p2>
        </lightning-card>   
</template>
```

p1 code :

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>      
            <c-child search-event="Application"></c-child>
    </lightning-card>   
</template>
```

p2 code:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>      
            <c-child search-event="candidate"></c-child>
    </lightning-card>   
</template>
```

Child js

```
import { LightningElement,track,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getIntegrationRecords from '@salesforce/apex/ClassName.getRecords';
export default class BbIntegrationLogMonitoringChart extends LightningElement {
    @api searchEvent;

    @wire(getIntegrationRecords,{searchEvent : '$searchEvent'})
    getEventData
}
```

Here in the child js only getting data for "Application" event and not the other event .I get only Application value and in p2 also application data, not candidate data.

Comment: Can you replicate this problem in a [demo](https://webcomponents.dev)? Right now, we don't have enough information to help you. There's no reason why the other value should not appear in the second child component.

Comment: Are you passing these values using any property of the p1, p2? If yes please add that code as well.

Comment: Added code for both js in child and parent

Comment: Try adding a getter and a setter for the searchEvent attribute in your child component. Also add debug logs in the setter. I think the value is passed properly, however your wire adapter is not retrieving any values.

Comment: I checked in my cild js only "Application" value is passed. Wire is working fine